# Creating a LINQ query based on two Lists and object array for testing parameters

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to separate out as much as possible an android from the business logic in order to speed things up.

Dotted around the code I have a piece of LINQ that looks like this

```
var jobItemDoneTest = JobItemsData.GetJobIfDone(wheelpos, theOrder.GetOrderItemStockItemID);
var jobsDoneList = new JobItemsData(theOrder.OrderData.jobItemsID).JobItemDone;
var stillToDo = theOrder
    .OrderItemsData
    .Where(p => jobsDoneList.All(p2 => p2.orderItemStockItemID != p.orderItemStockItemID))
    .Where(t => !t.description.Contains("2hr"))
    .Where(t => !t.description.Contains("Staff"))
    .ToList();
```

In other words, there is a comparison between two lists of to filter out some results.

What I'm trying to do is remove the instances of this to create a generic method in a business object class.

So far, I've got this

```
public List<T> GetWorkStillToDo<T, U>(List<T> orderItems, List<U> jobItems, params object[] searchList1, string searchList2)
{
   var stillToDo = orderItems.Where(p=>jobItems.Add(p2=>p2.orderItemStockItemID != p.orderItemStockItemID);
}
```

The problem is that if I want to search on different properties for p=> and `p2=>` and then filter on the where conditions, I'm getting lost and can't think of a way to iterate from n = 1 to n in the `searchList` object array and include them in a LINQ

Is

```
p2=>searchList[0].ToString() != searchList2
```

permitted within LINQ and how can I create the Where part of the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where clauses in LINQ are a `Func<object, bool>` object where `object` can be a generic if you have well-defined rules around them. The construction syntax is just a normal lambda. So:

```
Func<object, bool> where = obj => obj.Propery == delta;

return someEnumOrList.Where(where);
```

Wrapping this into a parameter lets you ad-hoc query against your items. You may need to provide an extension method, something like a `WhereAll` that takes an array of `Func<>` objects and checks them all. One idea for that would be:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereAll(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<object, bool>[] clauses)
{
    var result = enumerable;
    foreach(var c in clauses)
    {
        result = result.Where(c);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - would this just be fore the where clauses at the end or incorporate the All condition within the initial comparison?

Comment: @Nodoid I don't quite understand. I was assuming you were synthesizing your first example into the generic method so that you could streamline your `.Where`s. So, there would only be the `WhereAll` method in my example. Also, have you considered just putting your clauses into the same `Where` call?

Comment: Yeah, I did consider putting the clauses into the same where, but for some reason it was giving me a big performance hit over the original way I had it. Not sure why.